# Elliptic curves - mod $\mathcal{M}$ map

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, elliptic-curves, valuation-theory

I am struggling with an example from my lecture notes. Let $K$ be a non-Archimedean field with valuation ring $R=\{x:|x|\le 1\}$, maximal ideal $\mathcal{M}=\{x:|x|<1\}$ and residue field $k=R/\mathcal{M}$. Then the reduction map $R\to R/\mathcal{M}$ given by $r\mapsto r+\mathcal{M}$ is a surjection denoted by $a\mapsto \tilde{a}$.

Here are two examples, working in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. Firstly, if $a=3+2\cdot 5^1+\cdots$ then $\tilde{a}=3$. Secondly, $\tilde{(\frac{17}{3})}=2/3=2\cdot 2=4$.

With the definitions given above, I don't understand how we get these results in the examples. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a worthwhile question, but it has nothing to do with elliptic curves.

Comment: @Aphelli it relates to the reduction map of an elliptic curve

Comment: Maybe that’s your intended application, but the question itself has nothing to do with them. For your first example, $2\cdot 5^1+\ldots \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ has positive valuation (it’s $5$ times something), so it lies in the maximal ideal so $\tilde{a}=\tilde{3}$. In the second example, you have a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_5 \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_5$. Since $17=2+5 \cdot 3$,  $\tilde{17}=\tilde{2}$. The image of $17/3$ is $\tilde{17}/\tilde{3}=\tilde{2}/\tilde{3}$. Since $\tilde{2} \cdot \tilde{3}=\tilde{6}=\tilde{1}$, $\tilde{2}/\tilde{3}=\tilde{2 \cdot 2}/\tilde{3 \cdot 2}=\tilde{4}$.